# Open Windows Explorer from Windows Store app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps

It's actually a simple question, I have a n index of saved locations of my local network, like `\\server\file01`. I'm showing the user a grid with these entries and I want to open Windows Explorer when the user clicks on an item (path).

According to the documentation of [launchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701480.aspx), it is possible to do so since they state: `You must specify the privateNetworkClientServer capability in the manifest in order to launch intranet URIs, for example a file:/// URI pointing to a network location.`

For some unknown reason I cannot get it to work, the callback from launchUriAsync returns `false`. I started a thread at the [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/c8c821fb-46dc-4283-8b26-7ed9144a87bd) with no luck so fat, and I thought of posting here before paying for support.

Is there anything I am missing?

**Edit:** if I write the same uri to the folder in an html page with the a tag the windows explorer opens with the apecified folder. I thought Windows Explorer is the default app handler for the `file:///` protocol

Comment: I believe this api is more meant to launch actual associated applications. I'm going to do a little testing, but I think the blurb you mentioned above simply refers to a network file uri that has a registered application as a handler. Let me do a little testing here though.

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT That's how I read it too.  The only thing which made me think otherwise was that there was a section on how to register Windows 8 desktop applications as handlers.  Maybe windows explorer could be registered as a handler?

Comment: well, it 'kinda' is, through the Folder entry via HKLM/Software/Classes/Folder.. Have you first ensured you can launch a file on a network share? try a txt file for example. Also if you would get prompted for credentials, a file launch will fail as well.

Comment: sebastion, email me adamt  at micro-soft, have some details I'd like to work with you on this for and we can then update it here.