# Launch folder in Modern apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In my metro (Modern) app, I launch files using this:

```
if(item is StorageFile)
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(item as StorageFile);
```

How can I do the same with folders? I mean is it possible to launch a folder in the explorer?

Comment: I think, it is not possible.

Comment: See also [Open Windows Explorer from Windows Store app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912008/open-windows-explorer-from-windows-store-app).